# CSS3 transitions

Tags: css3

Можно ли задать стиль для элемента в момент, когда мышь наведена на другой элемент без использования скриптов?
Например, чтобы при наведении на div, менялась позиция элемента p.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->




<div></div>
<p> abc </p>
```

Comment: нет. здесь синтаксическая ошибка. Стоит добавить в вопрос html и показать на нем элементы к которым должны применяться стили

Comment: @Grundy это да, добавил это, чтобы примерно описать, что я хочу сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если они соседние, то можно использовать следующий селектор

```
div:hover + p {
  color: red;
}
```

Если `<p>` содержится внутри `<div>` (не важно как глубоко), то `div:hover путь_к_p`

А если в разных местах html-разметки, то тут уже надо применять js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {
              height:100px;
              width: 100px;
              background-color: grey;
            }
            div:hover + p {
              color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <p> abc </p>
    </body>        
</html>
```

**[UPD]**
Пример на jQuery:

```
var div = $('select1');
var p = $('select2');
$(div).on('mouseover', function(){
    $(p).toggleClass('someclass');
}
```

`.someclass` пишите где-нибудь заранее.

Comment: Если не сложно, добавьте к ответу пример использования.

Comment: А без jQuery можно выбрать кого-нибудь из детей элемента?

Comment: @SergeyPestov добавил jquery пример, селекторы то уж не буду разжевывать)

Comment: @СергейКоренюгин разобрался с селекторами) а можно вместо изменения стиля делать последовательные несколько изменений, как анимацию? по наведению мыши

Comment: @Юрий [пример с transitions](http://codepen.io/korenb/pen/vGXeKP). Те свойства, которые хочешь анимировать прописываешь через запятую  в `transitions` у объекта, а дальше обычным `:hover` меняешь значения этих свойств

Comment: @СергейКоренюгин а если они однотипные? То есть, например, 2 transform подряд: элемент двигается вправо на 100, меняет цвет на красный, потом двигается еще вправо на 100 и одновременно меняет цвет на синий

Comment: @Юрий в таком случае почитайте про css-анимации, там key-фреймы используются для пошагового анимирования. `transition` отлично подходит для `hover`.

Answer (score 0):

можно, если только сосед которого надо изменить стоит ниже по иерархии в дереве дом, обратно не получиться как в примере  наводишь на P, что бы изменился div

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background:gray;
}

div:hover ~ p{  background:orange;}

p:hover ~ div{  background:orange;}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p> abc </p>
```